# Cancelled Builds from Azure DevOps show up as failed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have been looking at using azure devops invoke in our organisation and you guys have a fantastic functionality!

I have one rather significant issue, however. Cancelled builds seem to show up as failed. This makes my pipeline red most of the time as we tend to let our pull request builds cancel mid-way through as we dont have them as a required pass to complete the PR.

.

Many thanks,

Comment: We are using ps script to create the tag and need to cancel that pipeline via 
az devops invoke --org https://dev.azure.com/orgname --area build --resource builds --route-parameters buildId=$(Build.BuildId) project="$(System.TeamProject)" --in-file xyz.txt  --http-method patch
pipelie is canceling but still showing failed in main branch history

Answer (score 0):

We suppose that you could check the two factors below.

1.If your are using yaml pipeline, you could define with below to [disable pull request triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines#pr-none)

```
pr: none # Disable pull request triggers.
```

2.You could disable the build validation policy below.

Check project setting> repositories>repo policies>branch policies>build validation, if this policy is enabled, then the pipeline will be triggered when pull request is created.
[image]
[image]